# Passing a Worksheet to a subroutine

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub SortWorksheet(ByVal sheet As Worksheet)
    Dim sStartColumn
    Dim iTopRow
    Dim sEndColumn
    Dim iBottomRow
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim sRange1 As String
    .
    .
    .
```

and I am calling the function like so:

```
SortWorksheet (DestSheet)
```

I am getting a runtime error on the above line saying "Object doesn't support this property or method"

DestSheet is a worksheet variable.

Why is this code not working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disregard, apparently in VBA the subroutine has be called like this

```
SortWorksheet DestSheet
```

Hey, I'm a C/C++/C# guy!  :)

Comment: Hey Bobby, if you prefer to use the parentheses when making a method call -- which I do, and given your C/C# background, I'm sure that you do to -- you can make use of VBA's `Call` keyword, as in `Call SortWorksheet(DestSheet)`

Comment: 4 years later and this saved me! Nice one. I keep putting the brackets in. It just seems... wrong.

Comment: 9 years later and still saves souls who try to do VBA